# Dynamics AX Form Item Ordering

Tags: forms, dynamics-ax-2012

For the most part, AX forms seem to follow the AOT layout and appear in order.  However, in some cases, the form items appear in seemingly arbitrary order, and in others, the items in the AOT won't even reorder.  No matter how you drag and drop items in the AOT, they are always in the same order.  This problem happened on occasion in AX 2009, but seems to be worse in AX 2012.  The only way I've found to get around it is to drop the non-reordering items and recreate them.

Has anyone else had similar experiences?  Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found that dragging and dropping only works part of the time.  However, if you use ALT+the arrow keys to move items up and down in the hierarchy, that seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your question it seems you are referring to control layout within a form. If your question is about something else please clarify.

To change form control layout you need to use AOT \Forms[FormName]\Designs\Design node. You can drag and drop controls and control groups. 
If you drag a control (let's call it "dragControl") and drop it on top of another control (say "dropControl"), then dragControl will be placed *after* dropControl. This means that if you want to change the first control of a control group, you need to drag the first control, as dropping any control on top of the first one will place them after the first control.

Also make sure your form does not have changes is some higher layer that would override the changes you are making in a lower layer.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You read my question correctly.  I am aware of editing in design view as well.  It is as if my items in the AOT are read-only when it comes to position.  Even in design view, when I drag and drop to reorder items, instead of dropping in the new position, they drop right back to their original location.  I can change the settings of the fields themselves, so I am certain this is not a permissions issue.  Also, nothing overrides the items in higher layers.  Thanks for responding.